# No highlighting on the unanswered tab of mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, bookmarks, ignored-tags

My [unanswered tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) looks like this, with favorite tags highlighted and ignored tags hidden:

[image: full version]

But on the mobile site the tags have no effect on the Unanswered tab:

[image: mobile version]

This appears to be a bug, because the tags do have the intended effect on the Questions tab of the mobile site. I first noticed this in mobile Opera on Android; the screenshots are from Chrome 23 on Windows 7; same happens in Firefox. The issue does not appear to be browser-dependent.

Comment: @Tim This is a sensitive subject. I don't want to offend people who like those areas of mathematics.

Comment: Sorry, @Pavel. I asked partially out of curiosity, and partially to understand the pictures in your post.

Comment: At least I know from your comment you haven't ignored me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting on the mobile version of the unanswered tab will start working with the next deploy.

Looks like I just straight up forgot to include it on that page, simple fix.